# knockoutjs foreach array select item value bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this select control which gets the data via knockoutjs:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="value: $root.selectedItem, options: $root.TeacherOptions(), optionsValue: 'TeacherId', optionsText: 'TeacherName', optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher'"></select>
```

What is happening now is for example if I select a value in one dropdown in the list, all the other dropdowns in the foreach list are getting the same value automatically.

Is it possible to change the functionality so that only the dropdown which is selected will change the value?

Short video of current functionality https://i.gyazo.com/1d70b77210e1daf3b14dc29a24bb01e4.gif

More code added (this is where I'm using the actual dropdown value):

```
 t.AddToCart = function (n) {
           if (!t.Busy()) {
               t.Busy(!0);
               n.Processing(!0);
               var i = t.SelectedColor();
               if (t.selectedItem()) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/webservices/ShopCartWS.asmx/AddItem",
                       data: "{'packId': " + n.Id + ", 'teacherId': " + t.selectedItem() + " }",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (i) {
                           if (i.d) {
                               $("#cart-status").sticky();
                               var r = i.d;
                               f(r);
                               n.Processing(!13);
                               t.Busy(!13);
                           }
                       },
                       error: function (n) {
                           u(n);
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                   alert('Choose Teacher First');
                   t.Busy(0);
                   n.Processing(0);
               }
           }
       };
```

How I'm getting the values:

```
   t._teacherOptions = ko.observable();

               function getTeacherList() {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/webservices/Teachers.asmx/GetTeachers",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (i) {
                           if (i.d) {
                               return t._teacherOptions(i.d);

                           }
                       },
                       error: function (n) {
                           u(n);
                       }
                   });
               }

               getTeacherList();

               t.TeacherOptions = ko.computed(function () {
                   return t._teacherOptions();
               });
```

Comment: This is happening because you have multiple selects all bound to
`$root.selectedItem`.

You'll need to bind each select to a different value.  The easiest way to do this create a new observable on the objects your iterating over.  If you provide more source I can probably help further.

Comment: @PeteG check how I'm using the value in the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different selects to be able to have different values, you need to provide distinct observables for their `value` bindings. It looks like you're creating these selects inside a `foreach`, so instead of `$root.selectedItem`, which is just one variable, have a variable in each element you're looping over.

```js
function TeacherOption(name, id) {
  return {
    TeacherName: name,
    TeacherId: id
  };
}

vm = {
  TeacherOptions: ko.observableArray([
    TeacherOption('one', 1),
    TeacherOption('two', 2),
    TeacherOption('pi', 3)
  ]),

  selectors: [{
    selectedItem: ko.observable()
  }, {
    selectedItem: ko.observable()
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectors">
  <select class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedItem, options: $root.TeacherOptions(), optionsValue: 'TeacherId', optionsText: 'TeacherName', optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher'"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the teachers from server side code, I just included how I'm getting the values>

Comment: @Laziale It doesn't matter where you're getting the teachers from. The issue is that you've used the same variable for each select's `value` binding. When that variable's value changes (because you select an option in one), all selects bound to that variable are going to update.

Comment: what do you think I should do in my code based on your proposed answer? Should I modify how the app is getting the values? Can you show me example based on my current functionality? Thx

Comment: I think your binding should be `value: selectedItem` instead of `value: $root.selectedItem`.